# Retriving data from firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch the data for website using java script. Problem I am getting is that I am unable to get the key of Users-->history-->location-->from-->(lat,lng). I am unable to find a syntax of it.

[image: Image of database]

Code I am trying is

```
   var ref = firebase.database().ref("history/" + keys  +"/location/from");

ref.on('value',gotDataa,errDataa);

function gotDataa(data){
    //console.log(data.val());
    var from = data.val();
    var keys=Object.keys(from);
    console.log(keys);
    for(var i=0 ; i<keys.length;i++)
    {
        var k=keys[i];
        var name = from[k].customer;
        var phone = from[k].driver;

        //console.log(name,phone,imag);
        $('ul').append( '<li>' + name +" : " + phone+ '</li>' );
    }
}
```

[image: error in code]

Comment: I assume `keys` is an array of keys and hence you need to loop over every key. You can't concatenate arrays and strings.

Comment: var ref = firebase.database().ref("history/" + keys  +"/location"); You have to use this reference to get both from and to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should print the lat and lng of each item in the history:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("history/");

ref.on('value',gotDataa,errDataa);

function gotDataa(data){
  data.forEach(function(child) {
    var from = data.val().location.from;
    console.log(from.lat+","+from.lng);
  });
}
```

Comment: this one is throwing an error

index.esm.js:74 [2018-05-06T15:06:37.751Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
    at file:///C:/Users/Arsalan/Desktop/New%20folder/index2.html:83:35

Comment: That means you don't have a location for that node.

Comment: I got that from different way by the way Thanks

Comment: Hello I need one more help.